# Strapi create new plugin plugin generator command does not work

Tags: strapi

I created a strapi project without using the strapi quickstart feature and now we are unable to create custom plugins for strapi.

Upon running the command to create a new plugin, we are getting the following error message:

```sh
error No generator called `plugin` found.
```

The command which I used was

```
npm run strapi generate:plugin my-form
```

Answer (score 3):

The strapi module under the `node_modules` folder was lacking the `strapi-generate-plugin` plugin.

Open the terminal in the `node_modules/strapi` folder of the project and install the plugin.

```
$ cd path/to/poject/node_modules/strapi && sudo npm i strapi-generate-plugin
```

Comment: that helped in my case, I consider this to be a bug since the documentation does not mention a solution such as this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for v4 and select plugin to create

> ```
> yarn strapi generate
> ```